# Recent Post With Excerpts in Sidebar

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am trying to either truncate or add excerpts to my recent posts in my wordpress theme. The problem is that I do not no where the file is located to make this modification. Can anyone help?

I am using the twentyten theme, and here is the website:http://www.callmewhatyouwantevencheap.com/

As you will see there on the site in the sidebar, I have recent posts and most popular post. I don't care about the most popular. I just care about truncating the Recent Posts.

Answer (score 0):

sidebar.php is where the wordpress sidebar hooks are called. You may just want to set up a custom WP_Query, or install a plugin which handles recent posts better, I know a lot of them have truncation built in.

Comment: Thanks Tallboy. I will give it a try, then come back and report my findings.